# primeng radiobutton active is not centered

Tags: html, css, primeng

i am using simple radio button in primeng. when the radio is selected, the inner dot is not centered. please find attachment about how it looks like.
[image]

Here is the code:

```css
.ui-radiobutton-box {
  border: 2px solid #06c !important;
}

.ui-radiobutton-box.ui-state-active {
  background-color: #fea;
}

.ui-state-active .fa {
  color: #dc1313;
}

.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-state-active">
  <span class="ui-radiobutton-icon fa fa-circle">

    </span>
</div>
```

How to make the red dot centered?

Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-radiobutton-box {
  border: 2px solid #06c !important;
  position: relative;
}

.fa {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Although, if know the red dot size, I would recommend to go with this:

```
.fa {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```